# Добавление пользователей в Google Developer Concole

Tags: google-play, google-console

Нужно добавить человека в мою консоль. Доступ к только одному нужному приложению я настроил. Но вот он все еще может смотреть на ВСЕ мои приложения в консоли. (Просто смотреть, без редактирования) Я этого не хочу. Как скрыть остальные приложения от него?